# Jenkins artifactory maven step fails silently using maven assembly plugin (Artifactory plugin 3.5.0)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I'm having problems building jar-with-dependencies using the Jenkins Artifactory plugin, which succeeds in other maven environments (Netbeans, Eclipse). I resolved an initial out-of-memory problem and two artifacts that weren't visible to the Artifactory mirror, and the log appears to show all of the dependencies being found and downloaded as expected. However, after the final dependency loads, the build step fails without any indication as to cause.

Previous builds have succeeded using the maven-jar-plugin, but for this particular integration we also want to build a jar containing all of the dependencies. I'm using maven-assembly-plugin 3.1.0, maven 3.5, Jenkins Artifactory plugin 3.5.0. Is there any way to identify what is causing the failure? The only exception in the log is "Maven build failed", which is not informative. Alternately, is there a better way to assemble a jar containing all dependencies, which has a track record with Artifactory?

Comment: Without error logout it's impossible to help...

Comment: It turns out this was a slave node resource issue. When -X was added to the maven line, we could eventually identify that it was a JNLP failure that is commonly solved by increasing the available slave node resource  (e.g. 960Mi, 500m for memory and CPU)